# When im going to delete dynamic array im getting error double free or corruption

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm new to C++. I am trying to run small Dynamic array application. I created two Dynamic arrays, then I delete two arrays using `delete[]`, but I'm getting an error double free or corruption

```
class DynamicArray
{
    private:
        X *array;
        int Size;
        int Reserve_size;

    public:
        DynamicArray()
        {
            array = new X[_DEFAULT_SIZE];
            Size = 0;
            Reserve_size = _DEFAULT_SIZE;
        }
        ~DynamicArray()
        {
            delete[] array;
        }

        void insert(X data)
        {
            if (Size == Reserve_size)
            {
                X *tempArray = new X[Reserve_size + _DEFAULT_SIZE];

                for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
                {
                    tempArray[i] = array[i];
                }
                //memcpy(newArray, array, sizeof(array));
                delete[] array;
                array = tempArray;
                delete[] tempArray;
                Reserve_size = Reserve_size + _DEFAULT_SIZE;
            }

            array[Size] = data;

            Size++;
        }

        X Get(int index)
        {
            return array[index];
        }
};
```

Comment: `array = tempArray;
            delete[] tempArray;` doesn't make much sense!

Comment: @curiousguy What do you mean by that . Im creating another array and copy it to previous array .

Comment: You seem to miss the basics of C++. Where are you coming from? A value based language? Reference based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete the array pointed to by `array` twice: once in `insert` and again in `~DynamicArray`.

Remember, for every call to `new` there must be exactly one, and only one, call to `delete`.  Also remember you don't `delete` pointers, you `delete` *the objects pointed to* by pointers.

Here's a set of graphics to hopefully clarify what's going on:

After constructor:

```
  array
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+
|       +-------->  |  |  | ... |  |
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+
```

After `X *tempArray = new X[Reserve_size + _DEFAULT_SIZE]`:

```
  array
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+
|       +-------->  |  |  | ... |  |
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+

tmpArray
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
|       +-------->  |  |  | ... |  | ... |  |  |
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
```

After `delete[] array`:

```
  array
+-------+
|       +-------->
+-------+

tmpArray
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
|       +-------->  |  |  | ... |  | ... |  |  |
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
```

After `array = tempArray`:

```
  array
+-------+
|       +---------+
+-------+         |
                  |
tmpArray          |
+-------+        +v-+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
|       +-------->  |  |  | ... |  | ... |  |  |
+-------+        +--+--+--+-----+--+-----+--+--+
```

After `delete[] tempArray`:

```
  array
+-------+
|       +---------+
+-------+         |
                  |
tmpArray          |
+-------+         v
|       +-------->
+-------+
```

In `~DynamicArray`:

```
  array
+-------+
|       +---------+
+-------+         |
                  |
                  |
                  v
```

Whoops, `array` isn't pointing at anything, so you can't `delete[]` the thing it's pointing to.